# pandas barchart color the bar to matching column data

Tags: pandas, plot

I have a graph where values are the number of colors ( 4 red, 5 blue, 1 white) etc.
How do I color the bars to match the data, when I try my code the reds are green , the whites are black for example.

```
def this_family():
    data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM toys WHERE Date  >= ?   ', conn, params=(this_month,))
    my_colours = [item for item in data['Family'].drop_duplicates()] # get a list of all the colours effected
    c = dict(zip(my_colours, my_colours))
    data.groupby(['Name','Family']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, edgecolor='black',figsize=(14,6),)
    plt.savefig("mysite/Static/this_family.png",bbox_inches = "tight"
```

Where the column 'Family' holds a color.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by ordering the initial database query.